# How to compress / decompress a serialized Pandas Dataframe with PyArrow?

Tags: compression, pyarrow

I am using Redis to store a Pandas dataframe.  I am using PyArrow for serialization and would like to add compression.

I can serialize/deserialize dataframes with no problems.  I can also compress the serialized dataframe.  However, I cannot seem to decompress it.

When I try to decompress, I get:  **ValueError: Must pass decompressed_size for lz4 codec**

So, I add the size of the object and get:  **ArrowIOError: Corrupt Lz4 compressed data.**

Thinking it might be a problem with Pandas dataframes, I tried using a simple text string but got the same result.  I thought perhaps it was a problem with the lz4 codec but the errors occur with 'gzip' also.  Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
import pandas
import pyarrow
import sys


df = pandas.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],'B':[4,5,6]})

ser = pyarrow.serialize(df).to_buffer()
comp = pyarrow.compress(ser,asbytes=True)

dec = pyarrow.decompress(comp)  
# Gives ValueError: Must pass decompressed_size for lz4 codec

siz = sys.getsizeof(ser) #siz = 56
dec = pyarrow.decompress(comp,decompressed_size = siz) 
#Gives ArrowIOError: Corrupt Lz4 compressed data.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sys.getsizeof provides the wrong size.  The following code round trips:

```
import pandas
import pyarrow
import sys


df = pandas.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],'B':[4,5,6]})

ser = pyarrow.serialize(df).to_buffer()
comp = pyarrow.compress(ser,asbytes=True)
siz = len(ser) #siz = 3912
dec = pyarrow.decompress(comp,decompressed_size = siz)
pyarrow.deserialize(dec)
```

Comment: This worked!  Thanks so much.  I spent a good part of the day trying to solve this only to find out I was over-complicating it (as usual).

Comment: How can I choose to read just a few columns instead of deserializing the entire file in this case?

Comment: This should be a different question.  Arrow recently added the ability to compress individual buffers but this question was about compressing an entire arrow dataframe which doesn't allow for individual column access.